# Correct implementation of List Iterator methods

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

To better learn about Iterators, I am to write them myself to try and get the correct functionality of them. I'm having an issue getting the correct behavior out of the `ListIterator` previous method.

For example, the JavaDoc states that:

> Alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.

**My Iterator**

```
class Node<Item> {
    public Item data;
    public Node<Item> next;
    public Node<Item> previous;

    public Node() {
        data = null;
        next = null;
        previous = null;
    }

    public Node(Item i, Node<Item> n, Node<Item> p) {
        data = i;
        next = n;
        previous = p;
    }
}

public ListIterator<Item> listIterator() {

    return new ListIterator<Item>() {

        private Node<Item> n = first;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return n.next != last;
        }

        public Item next() {
            n = n.next;
            return n.data;
        }

        //TODO
        public void remove() {
        }

        public boolean hasPrevious() {
            return n.previous != first;
        }

        public Item previous() {
            n = n.previous;
            return n.data;
        }
    };
}
```

Now, when I test it out, I'm having incorrect behavior with the `previous()` method.

**TEST**

```
LinkedList<String> lst2 = new LinkedList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        lst2.add("" + "data".substring(i, i + 1));

    ListIterator<String> it2 = lst2.listIterator();
    System.out.println("\nTest the list iterator.\nThe test list is " + lst2 + "\n");

    while (it2.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("next is " + it2.next());
        System.out.println("previous is " + it2.previous());
        if (removeImplemented) {
            it2.remove();
            System.out.println("After remove: " + lst2);
        }
        System.out.println("next is " + it2.next());
    }

    System.out.println("\nHere is how the built-in Java ArrayList class works\n");
    ArrayList<String> lst3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        lst3.add("" + "data".substring(i, i + 1));

    ListIterator<String> it3 = lst3.listIterator();
    System.out.println("Test list iterator.\nThe test list is " + lst3 + "\n");

    boolean remove = false;

    while (it3.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("next is " + it3.next());
        System.out.println("previous is " + it3.previous());
        if (remove) {
            it3.remove();
            System.out.println("After remove: " + lst3);
        }
        System.out.println("next is " + it3.next());
    }
```

**My Results**

```
The test list is [d, a, t, a]

next is d
previous is null //incorrect
next is d
next is a
previous is d //incorrect
next is a
next is t
previous is a //incorrect
next is t
next is a
previous is t //incorrect
next is a
```

**Correct Results**

```
The test list is [d, a, t, a]

next is d
previous is d
next is d
next is a
previous is a
next is a
next is t
previous is t
next is t
next is a
previous is a
next is a
```

Now, to my understanding, the second set of results is the correct behavior of the `ListIterator`. So, what can I do to achieve this behavior? From what I've read, it has something to do with the cursor being moved to the element before, and not the element itself. I'm having trouble thinking of a way to implement this.

Comment: The javadoc is referring to the `next()` and `previous()` methods of `Listiterator` but it looks like you're returning fields `next` and `previous` of whatever class `Node n` is, thus your different behavior.

Comment: @DanielWiddis so would the current behavior be correct then?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'correct'. If you're trying to match `ListIterator` then obviously not, as your output doesn't match.   I don't see where you update n.data which is the value you return so I have no idea what you're trying to do under the hood.

Comment: how are you calling your previous() and next() and then how are you updating your iterator?

Comment: @KP I will add more relevant code

Comment: @KP code has been updated, let me now if I can provide anything else useful.

Comment: @DanielWiddis code has been updated.

Comment: I think you need to store the value of `n.data` before you set `n` to `n.prev`, and return the stored `n.data`.

Comment: To be more clear, next is "advance pointer and then return next value" while previous is "return this value and then move pointer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have properly implemented the behavior for `next()`, advancing to the next node and returning the new value.

However, the behaviour for `previous()` needs to return the existing value before you change to the previous node.   You'll have to store `n.data` in a temporary variable before updating `n`, and then return the stored temporary value.

For example:

```
public Item previous() {
    Item temp = n.data;
    n = n.previous;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way you could provide an example of this? While it makes sense, I'm still having trouble implementing it into my code.

Comment: @23k I updated my answer to include a specific example.  It seems trivial based on what I explained.  Is there another difficulty with the code?

Comment: Where am I supposed to update temp? On the first pass through, `n.data == null`. So every time temp is returned in previous, a null value is given.

Comment: If you haven't ever done "next()" then previous would indeed be null.  But once you've done `next()` then there should be a value in `n.data`.