# Writing a ListIterator that mirrors Java's built in Iterator

Tags: java, list, iterator

So I'm attempting to mirror the functionality of Java's `ListIterator`. The only thing I'm having trouble wrapping my head around is getting the `previous()` method working correctly.

Here's what I have.

```
public ListIterator300<Item> listIterator() {

    return new ListIterator300<Item>() {

        private Node<Item> n = first;

            public boolean hasNext() {
                 return n.next != last;
            }

            public Item next() {
                n = n.next;
                return n.data;
            }

            public void remove() {
            }

            public boolean hasPrevious() {
               return n.previous != first;
            }

            public Item previous() {
                n = n.previous;
                return n.data;
            }
        };
    }
```

So, the issue I'm running into is having the `previous()` and `next()` methods, when called subsequently, return the same number. Now I've read that the built in `ListIterator` uses a cursor. Is there any general tips how I could implement this into my code?

For example

`[1 2 3 4]`

`next() -> 1`

`previous() -> 1`

`next() -> 1`

`next() -> 2`

Comment: @Joni the data is initialized to null. I can post the rest of the code if it would be useful

Comment: This must be somebody's homework. I just answered this identical question here a day ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403794/correct-implementation-of-list-iterator-methods/37404073#37404073

Comment: Use the @DanielWiddis notation to get my attention.  I'm not normally notified of general comments.

Comment: You did not take the change I suggested to store `n.data` in a temporary variable before updating `n = n.previous` in your `previous()` method.   Add a `Node<Item> temp = n.data`; then `n = n.previous;`, then `return temp;`.  Is there another specific problem you have?

Comment: @DanielWiddis I will post specifics in a second

Comment: (Oops, on the above, type of temp should be `Item`)

Comment: You have a "fake" first node that holds no data? Do you also have a fake last node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking:

```
n.next != last;
```

check:

```
n != last;
```

and the same for:

```
n.previous != first;
```

replace it with:

```
n != first;
```

Do you see why ?

Comment: If I had to take a guess, checking n.next and n.previous would always put it one ahead or one behind?

Comment: Don't guess - draw it on a piece of paper! When `n.next == last` it still means that you have a "next". only when `n == last` you don't have any "next". And the same goes for previous respectively.